print with bluetooth printer in swift
I have an problem. I want an App that sent data to an XP-370B via BLE. I want to send Text.
The problem is that when i use the App from the App Store i can succsessfully send Text to the XP-370B but when I try to this with my App it does not work.
my app is connect to printer but I can't send text to printer with my app.
my printer : (https://www.xprintertech.com/bluetooth-compact-thermal-label-printer-xp-370b)
Note : my printer is : thermal-label-printer ( not receipt printer )
this setting for printer in setting App :



after send text not any problem but the printer not print any thing
Here is the Code from the App:


import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    
    var centralManager : CBCentralManager!
    var myBluetoothPeripheral : CBPeripheral!
    var myCharacteristic : CBCharacteristic!
    
    @objc override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        self.centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        
        let button = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 80, y: 80, width: 80, height: 50)
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.setTitle("print", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(funcPrint), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)
    }
    
    @objc func funcPrint()
    {
        let estr = "ISO-8859-6"
        let cfe = CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding(estr as CFString)
        
        let se = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(cfe)
        let sse = String.Encoding(rawValue: se)
        
        let hexs = [0x1B, 0x61, 0x01 ,0x1B, 0x21, 0x08 ,0x1D, 0x56, 66, 0x00]
        
        var hexString = "hello word"
        
        for all in hexs {
            if let scalar = UnicodeScalar(all) {
                hexString.append(Character(scalar))
            }
        }
        
        let theData = hexString.data(using: sse)!
        self.myBluetoothPeripheral.writeValue(theData, for: self.myCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)
        
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        if peripheral.name == "XP-370B" {
            self.myBluetoothPeripheral = peripheral
            self.myBluetoothPeripheral.delegate = self
            self.centralManager!.stopScan()
            self.centralManager!.connect(myBluetoothPeripheral, options: nil)
            
        }
    }
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        
        print("central = \(central)") // debug is : <CBCentralManager: 0x6000011641e0>
        
        print("peripheral = \(peripheral)") // debug is : <CBPeripheral: 0x600001b7c1a0, identifier = F7C39720-9670-740E-0479-48FD23C5D59C, name = XP-370B, mtu = 23, state = connected>
        
        
        peripheral.delegate = self
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
        
        self.centralManager!.stopScan()
    }
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        
        self.centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        
    }
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        
        print("peripheral = \(peripheral)") // debug is : <CBPeripheral: 0x600001ca92b0, identifier = F7C39720-9670-740E-0479-48FD23C5D59C, name = XP-370B, mtu = 185, state = connected>
        
        if let servicePeripheral = peripheral.services as [CBService]? {
            
            for service in servicePeripheral {
                
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
                
            }
            
        }
    }
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        
        
        print("peripheral = \(peripheral)") // debug is : <CBPeripheral: 0x600001672150, identifier = F7C39720-9670-740E-0479-48FD23C5D59C, name = XP-370B, mtu = 185, state = connected>
        
        
        /*
        print("service = \(service)") // debug is : 
         
        service = <CBService: 0x6000021d0740, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 49535343-FE7D-4AE5-8FA9-9FAFD205E455>
        service = <CBService: 0x6000021de180, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 18F0>
        service = <CBService: 0x6000021dd6c0, isPrimary = YES, UUID = E7810A71-73AE-499D-8C15-FAA9AEF0C3F2>
        service = <CBService: 0x6000021dd3c0, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Device Information>
        */
        
        
        
        if let characterArray = service.characteristics as [CBCharacteristic]? {
            
            for cc in characterArray {
                
                if(cc.uuid.uuidString == "BEF8D6C9-9C21-4C9E-B632-BD58C1009F9F") {
                    myCharacteristic = cc
                    peripheral.readValue(for: cc)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        
        var msg = ""
        
        switch central.state {
        case .poweredOff:
            msg = "Bluetooth is Off"
        case .poweredOn:
            self.centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        case .unsupported:
            msg = "Error Connect Bluetooth"
        default:
            break
        }
        
        if msg != ""
        {
            print("error : \(msg)")
        }
    }
    
    
}


What settings do those switches change?  If your printer is in TSC/TSPL mode then you need to send valid TSPL data, which your code does not do.

machine Type is : Label , and printer mode is : TSC Command

By using these buttons , the printer is converted from : receipt printing system to label printing system or vice versa ، and I want to use label printing not receipt printer

Ok, so if your printer is in TSC mode you need to send TSPL.  The data you are sending looks like it is probably ESC/POS

Ok , how can I send TSPL ?

The same way you are sending data now; create the tspl string, convert it to data and send it to the printer

Can you write the code for that ? > create the tspl string  ،، I do not know that

http://www.bar-tech.com.tw/eng/download/12790046025_TSPL_TSPL2_Programming_2009_06_24.pdf

I apologize, can you provide me with an example code?
